# Generating data using PhpExcelTemplator

Tags: php, arrays, excel, foreach

I'm not able to generate the result within the brackets `[]` using export tool from [alhimik1986/php-excel-templator](https://github.com/alhimik1986/php-excel-templator).

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $input = $row['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_PPU_COD'];
}

PhpExcelTemplator::saveToFile(
    '../excel_templates/' . $file_template,
    '../temp/' . $file_export,
    [
        '{Cliente}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_NOME'],
        '{Contrato_Num}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_NUMERO'],
        '{Contrato_Nome}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_NOME'],
        '[Codigo]' => [array($input)], //['Value1','Value2']
    ]
);

//Download
header("Location: ../temp/$file_export");
```

Comment: So what does `$input` actually contain? If that is a string containing several comma-separated values, then don’t think `array($input)` would create an array with multiple items from that, it doesn’t - it creates an array containing _one_ value.

Comment: I corrected your code because it had a brace at the end of the `}`. Also, don't write `foreach ($var as $var)` as it may cause you problems (overwriting the variable). In addition, you iterate through the query results, but each iteration overwrites `$input`. You have a lot of mistakes here. Try to get the code working for the static data first (create an array of data in the code), then when that works for you, add new elements such as fetching data from the database.

Comment: Right! The $ input contains a select and would have to generate value1, value 2, etc.

When I put the static information, it works normally, I just couldn't find a way to insert the array inside the []

Comment: Below the code that works. Where it is 10, 20, 30, it would be a select mysql.

`PhpExcelTemplator::saveToFile('../excel_templates/'.$file_template, '../temp/'.$file_export,  
[
    '{Cliente}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_NOME'],
    '{Contrato_Num}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_NUMERO'],
    '{Contrato_Nome}' => $row_ctr['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_NOME'],
    '[Codigo]' => ['10','20','30'],
]);
    
//Download
header("Location: ../temp/$file_export");
}`

Comment: Correct your question by [edit] it, add the code snippets that work for you, and provide the data you get as a result of the SQL query. You don't tell us what this SQL looks like, so we don't know what it looks like.

Comment: You should iterate over `$result` instead `$sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a working code, input data and result:

```php
PhpExcelTemplator::saveToFile(
    __DIR__ . '/template.xls',
    __DIR__ . '/output.xls',
    [
        '{current_date}' => '2020-12-13',
        '[date]' => ['2020-12-14', '2020-12-15', '2020-12-16',],
        '[code]' => ['111', '333', '999'],
        '[status]' => ['OK', 'FAIL', 'GOOD'],
        '[[hours]]' => [['00:00', '06:00', '12:00', '18:00']],
        '[manager]' => ['Antonio', 'Fernando'],
        '[[manager_hours]]' => [
            ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
            ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4']
        ]
    ]
);
```

*template.xls*

[image: screenshot of template.xls]

*output.xls*

[image: screenshot of output.xls]

Please try to use my code first to get my result. Then replace with your code fragments - that way you can spot where you make mistakes.

---

EDIT:

```php
$input = [];
$queryResult = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
    $input[] = $row['CGS_EMPRESA_CLIENTE_CTR_PPU_COD'];
}

PhpExcelTemplator::saveToFile(
    'input.xls',
    'output.xls',
    [
        '[Codigo]' => $input,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked perfectly!

Comment: My problem was the lack of use of "mysqli_fetch_assoc". Now everything went well, and I will adapt the code to generate several templates in excel. Thank you very much!

Comment: To be precise, function `mysql_fetch_assoc($res)` is the same as function `mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)`. One of the problems was that you iterated over the columns of the first database record returned, instead iterating over a collection of records.